# How do I set an image resource with a new drawable on click? Android studio

Tags: java, android

This program swaps the graphic on an image and a button. Swapping the graphic on the button works correctly but swapping the graphic on the image crashes the program.Having worked on this for some time I still can't figure out why it won't run.

```
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public void blackButtons(View v3) {
    ImageButton blue = (ImageButton) v3.findViewById(R.id.bluebuttonclick);
    ImageView r1 = (ImageView) v3.findViewById(R.id.test1);

    if (v3 == blue){
       blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackbtimage);
       r1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebtimage);


    }

    }
```

Comment: can we see the logcat??

Comment: probably the imageview with the id of "test1" does not exist in the layout you're working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only find r1 if v3 is the parent of it. This means if v3 is an imagebutton which you confirm on your `if(v3 == blue)` the r1 can't be found from v3. Try instead `ImageView r1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test1);` if your function is called inside of the activity which layout has to have the ImageView defined in it's xml file. 
 Your code should give you an NullPointerException on the `r1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebtimage);`